# Augmented assignment with frozenset

Tags: python, set, immutability, augmented-assignment

I just tried an augmented assignment on a frozenset, and the result surprised me:

```
>>> x = frozenset(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
>>> x
frozenset({'foo', 'baz', 'bar'})
>>> x &= {'baz', 'qux', 'quux'}
>>> x
frozenset({'baz'})
```

This isn't supposed to happen, is it?  Aren't frozensets immutable?

Comment: Check the `id` of `x` before and after the operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you surprised?

You knew the term "augmented assignment" so there is no problem finding the ["Python Data Model on augmented arithmetic assignments"](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iand__) (emphasis mine):

> These [`__i***__`] methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying self) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, self). **If a specific method is not defined, the augmented assignment falls back to the normal methods.** For instance, if `x` is an instance of a class with an `__iadd__()` method, x += y is equivalent to `x = x.__iadd__(y)` . Otherwise, `x.__add__(y)` and `y.__radd__(x)` are considered, [...]

```
>>> x = frozenset(['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
>>> x.__iand__
[...]
AttributeError: 'frozenset' object has no attribute '__iand__'
```

So it has no `__iand__` method so the code you perform is:

```
>>> x = x & {'baz', 'qux', 'quux'}
```

The `__and__` method however is defined by `frozenset`:

```
>>> x & {'baz', 'qux', 'quux'}
frozenset({'baz'})
```

However you lost your reference to the original `frozenset`: `x`:

```
>>> y = x   # that doesn't do a copy, it's just to check if `x` has changed"
>>> x &= {'baz', 'qux', 'quux'}
>>> x is y  # check if they reference the same object!
False
>>> x, y
(frozenset({'baz'}), frozenset({'bar', 'baz', 'foo'}))
```

But that just follows the ["Principle of least astonishment"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). You wanted the `__and__` and you made it clear that you didn't want to keep your original `x` - an in-place operation also would have altered it!

So again: Why did that surprise you?

Answer (score 2):

Frozensets *are* immutable, except your assignment isn't mutating the original frozenset - you are just reassigning the variable `x` to the result of your binary operator `&`. As noted by user2357112 in the comments, `x &= {'baz', 'qux', 'quux'}` falls back on `x = x  & {'baz', 'qux', 'quux'}` after an [`__iand__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iand__) method is not found, leaving you with a non-mutating operation.

This behavior can be seen for other augmented operations on immutable types that don't supply `__iand__`, e.g.

```
In[1]: x = (1, 2, 3)
In[2]: id(x)
Out[2]: 761782862328
In[3]: x += (4, 5)
In[4]: id(x)   # we now have a different id
Out[4]: 761780182888
In[5]: x[2] = 3  # an actual mutating operation
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```